# How to take n random items from a collection in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a function that takes n random items from a collection such that the same item is never picked twice. I could accomplish this quite easily:

```
(defn take-rand [n coll]
  (take n (shuffle coll)))
```

But I have a pesky requirement that I need to return the same random subset when the same seed is provided, i.e.

```
(defn take-rand [n coll & [seed]] )

(take-rand 5 (range 10) 42L)  ;=> (2 5 8 6 7)
(take-rand 5 (range 10) 42L)  ;=> (2 5 8 6 7)
(take-rand 5 (range 10) 27L)  ;=> (7 6 9 1 3)
(take-rand 5 (range 10))      ;=> (9 7 8 5 0)
```

I have a solution for this, but it feels a bit clunky and not very idiomatic. Can any Clojure veterans out there propose improvements (or a completely different approach)?

Here's what I did:

```
(defn take-rand
  "Returns n randomly selected items from coll, or all items if there are fewer than n.
  No item will be picked more than once."
  [n coll & [seed]]
  (let [n (min n (count coll))
        rng (if seed (java.util.Random. seed) (java.util.Random.))]
    (loop [out [], in coll, n n]
      (if (or (empty? in) (= n 0))
        out
        (let [i (.nextInt rng n)]
          (recur (conj out (nth in i))
                 (concat (take i in) (nthrest in (inc i)))
                 (dec n)))))))
```

Comment: Is this not exactly the sort of thing that `memoize` is for - or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'm no clojure veteran, but how about:

```
(defn shuffle-with-seed
  "Return a random permutation of coll with a seed"
  [coll seed]
  (let [al (java.util.ArrayList. coll)
        rnd (java.util.Random. seed)]
    (java.util.Collections/shuffle al rnd)
    (clojure.lang.RT/vector (.toArray al))))

(defn take-rand [n coll & [seed]]
    (take n (if seed 
              (shuffle-with-seed coll seed)
              (shuffle coll))))
```

`shuffle-with-seed` is similiar to clojure's [`shuffle`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/shuffle), it just passes an instance of [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to Java's [`java.util.Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29).

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `shuffle` function in your first solution with the reproducible one. I will show you my solution below:

```
(defn- shuffle'
  [seed coll]
  (let [rng (java.util.Random. seed)
        rnd #(do % (.nextInt rng))]
    (sort-by rnd coll)))

(defn take-rand'
  ([n coll]
     (->> coll shuffle (take n)))
  ([n coll seed]
     (->> coll (shuffle' seed) (take n))))
```

I hope this solution make results you expected:

```
user> (take-rand' 5 (range 10))
(5 4 7 2 6)

user> (take-rand' 5 (range 10))
(1 9 0 8 5)

user> (take-rand' 5 (range 10))
(5 2 3 1 8)

user> (take-rand' 5 (range 10) 42)
(2 6 4 8 1)

user> (take-rand' 5 (range 10) 42)
(2 6 4 8 1)

user> (take-rand' 5 (range 10) 42)
(2 6 4 8 1)
```

Comment: Very nice! I should test the performance of your solution against the accepted answer that uses `java.util.Collections.shuffle()`.